# Read from text file to a string?

Tags: python, string, append, python-2.x

I am reading the values from a text file to a string. When al the values are read into the string i need to put them into quotes and be separated by a comma.

An example of this would be in the text file i would have:

```
123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789
```

and I read it into my string `data_to_read` and I would like it to show:

```
data_to_read = "1234567892","1234567892","1234567892","1234567892"
```

I can read it into the string but cannot figure out how to add the quotes and commas.

```
with open('C:\uiautomation\Test_Files\Securities_to_Delete.txt', 'r') as input:
    data_to_read = "".join(input.readlines()[1:])
    print data_to_read
```

This outputs:

```
'123456789\n123456789\n123456789\n123456789'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `replace` string method to do this:

```
'"' + data_to_read.replace("\n", '","') + '"'
```

Answer (score 1):

This works also for python versions that support f-strings:

```
new_str = ','.join([f'"{item}"' for item in data_to_read.split()])
```

Comment: They're using python 2.

Comment: I noticed that after posting, thank you. f-strings weren't introduced until python 3.6 but a similar approach could be taken using python 2.x syntax